# What is salami attack

Tags: security

I searched online and I could come up with this jibberish definition

> Salami attack refers to a series of many small actions, often
>   performed by clandestine means, that as an accumulated whole produces
>   a much larger action or result that would be difficult or unlawful to
>   perform all at once

I could understand that it's a series of small attacks

What does **clandestine means** refer to?

How does the attack takes place?

And what are the countermeasures for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example may help.

There are some relatively famous cases, of *e.g.* employees installing software or hardware and manipulating transactions with such miniscule amounts, that no one identifies the occurrence of fraud for lengthy amounts of time.

One relatively known example is a case, where chips were installed on gasoline pumps, overcharging customers only ever so slightly - this is also what **clandestine** refers to. The stolen sum becomes very large over time, but individual transactions are so small that they are barely noticeable.

To transfer this to a non-IT example:

#### Not salami:

Bank robbery, stealing 2 million directly.

#### Salami:

Being a bank employee and stealing miniscule amounts over a large period of time accumulating 2 million.

#### Further reading:

http://www.mekabay.com/nwss/116p--salami_fraud.pdf